# Is there a way to replenish ammo in battle without using a Capture Point?

Tags: war-thunder

In War Thunder it seems that your tank's ammo can be refilled at Capture Points. Usually, this isn't an issue as most tank can carry more ammunition than can realistically be used. However, for Tank Destroyers which may [hold as few as ten shells](https://wiki.warthunder.com/Chi-Ha_LG), fast-firing and low-capacity [rocket vehicles](https://wiki.warthunder.com/BM-13N), and nearly any anti-aircraft vehicle it is feasible to run out of ammo in battle.

When this happens is there any alternative to driving to a capture point to replenish ammunition? This is hardly an appealing action when in a heavily-armored tank, and far less attractive when driving a lightly-armored SPAA.

Is there any way to get ammo in a Ground RB battle? If all Capture Points are held by the enemy team then ammo seemingly cannot be refilled at all. Can I get it from my spawn site or perhaps from other players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Side note: If you always run out of ammo, play around the point. The capture point is the purpose of the game, not sniping from the hill. Defend the point, snipe when the point is not being attacked, then you'll have easy access to ammo.